# Alternatives to Amplify.js

Tags: javascript

I was looking for a good abstraction for localstorage and came across amplify.js, but [it seems it is no longer being developed](https://github.com/mikehostetler/amplify/issues/110). Is there a good alternative? I like the extras that come with amplify (pubsub/ajax) but it is the localstorage (preferably with fallbacks) that I am most concerned about.